# DQN ANN input vs Linear function approximator feature vector

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn

So when using semi-gradient td(0) you need to convert your state representation into a feature vector that represents the state and as far as I know, should not be correlated.

Is the input on the ANN of a DQN the same? should it be a feature vector that represents the state? What considerations should one have when creating such vector?